# Get statement which fire trigger in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I tried to get the statement which fire my trigger, and i found anything.... There was a tip in oracle 8i, but that doesn't work now.

I am on Oracle 10 and 11g.

I tried with BEFORE or AFTER trigger, and with SQL_ID or PREV_SQL_ID in v$session with this query :

```
 select substr(e.program,1,20),sql_text into l_program, sql_text 
 from v$sql s, v$session e
  where s.sql_id = e.sql_id
  and e.status = 'ACTIVE'
    and e.sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID')
    and rownum = 1;
```

Either i got current statement (in v$session), either the statement before my update query which fire the trigger....

I tried compound trigger, too, but same...  Because i thought, if i tried to get the statement before or after statement, it will work... Nothing....

Someone have an idea ? I don't believe there is no solution...

Answer (score 0):

We have triggers like this, to capture the sql, that worked for years, but became unreliable in oracle 10, and stopped working outright in Oracle 11.

FYI:  Compound triggers aren't available in Oracle 10 (but won't help anyway).

The only reliable way to capture the sql statement now is through [Standard Auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG55281).

You'd have to select the types of operations you want to audit, as well as applying it to all tables you want to capture the sql against.